# Left outer join with subqueries with an inner join

Tags: sql-server, join, criteria, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I have a SQL query which I want to convert using Criteria API.

I want to combine left outer join of `EMPLOYEE` with the result set from the subquery which is querying different tables with inner joins.

```
SELECT 
    E1.EMPNO, E1.LASTNAME, E1.WORKDEPT, D1.DEPTNAME ,O1.OrgId
FROM 
    E1.EMPLOYEE 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT * 
     FROM Organization O1 
     INNER JOIN Departmental D2 ON D2.OrgId = O1.OrgId
     INNER JOIN Departmental D3 ON D3.OrgId = E2.OrgId) D1 ON D1.DeptNo = E1.WORKDEPT
```

Comment: Here you need to write FROM EMPLOYEE E1 as you are using table alias E1 in select statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the query as shown below. Here you have given same alias `D1` for same table `Departmental` join multiple times.

```
SELECT 
    E1.EMPNO, E1.LASTNAME, E1.WORKDEPT, D1.DEPTNAME ,O1.OrgId
FROM 
    EMPLOYEE E1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT * 
     FROM Organization O1 
     INNER JOIN Departmental D2 ON D2.OrgId = O1.OrgId
     INNER JOIN Departmental D3 ON D3.OrgId = E2.OrgId
     -- add where condition if required
    ) D1 
     ON D1.DeptNo = E1.WORKDEPT
   -- add where condition if required
```

Comment: Want to be in Criteria

Comment: You can put where condition in either inner or outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following SQL query

```
SELECT 
    E1.EMPNO, E1.LASTNAME, E1.WORKDEPT, D1.DEPTNAME, 
    D1.O1OrgId
FROM E1.EMPLOYEE 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
    select
        O1.OrgId as O1OrgId,
        D1.DeptNo as D1DeptNo
    from Organization O1 
    inner join Departmental D1 
        on D1.OrgId=O1.OrgId
) D1 
    on D1.D1DeptNo = E1.WORKDEPT
```

Table alias used within a sub-select cannot be referenced from outer SQL SELECT statement

There is a scope for the table alias, too

You can only reference to the fields that are in the SELECT list from a sub-select statement in the outer query

Comment: ya Query might not be a correct one, but question is on Criteria API how to write Leftouterjoin with subqueries having different tables with inner joins

Comment: Corrected the query, please help

Comment: Your qyery has still problems. For example, E2 aliased table does not exist, but you used E2 alias in a join condition. In the field list of the outer SELECT, you have a column "O1.OrgId" which has undefined alias O1. O1 alias is visible only in inner SELECT statement. All output fields of the inner SELECT should be referenced as D1 in the outer SELECT statement